# Queue in laravel with redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I'm having trouble with an application where i do a lot of api calls in the backend. Because of this the application gets a timeout error.

Someone suggested I should use Queues. I have tried to do so with redis. The function goes in the job and uses the handler but I expected the page to load with the data I give it without the data from the api while the api-call is going through on the background. Instead it just goes through like when i hadn't used the queue. I tried to follow a tutorial to do this but they weren't doing exactly the same and I couldn't adjust it so it would work for me.

For info about what i do in the job. I get comments out a csv and the I use the numbers in the comments to call to the api and i get a json of like 8-10 fields. I need to call the api about 650 times so it takes o long when i want to save the data to the database. I use one insert at a time to use "caching" so i wont do the same call twice.

This is the controller where I call on the job.

```
class ImportController extends Controller
{
public function checkErrors(Request $request)
{
    $this->checkAgainstDocuments($csv_id);
    $supplierErrorIds=$this->checkSupplierErrors($parameters, $company , $csv_id);
    $timesheetErrors=TsData::whereIn('id', $supplierErrorIds)->sortable()->paginate(20);
    return view('show_errors', compact('timesheetErrors', 'company', 'csv_id'));
}

public function checkAgainstDocuments($csv_id)
{
    GetFromDocumentsAPI::dispatch($csv_id)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
}
}
```

This is the job I use:

```
class GetFromDocumentsAPI implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $csv_id;
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($csv_id)
{
    //
    $this->csv_id=$csv_id;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $comments = TsData::select('id', 'comments')->where('csv_id', $this->csv_id)->get()->toArray();

    $commentIDs = array();

    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        preg_match_all('/(\d{5,})/', $comment['comments'], $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        foreach ($out as $item) {
            $commentIDs[$comment['id']] = $item;
        }
    }

    $commentIDs = array_filter($commentIDs);

    $apiKey=config('app.apiKey');

    $documentsResponse = array();

    Issue::truncate();

    $arrayTest=[];

    foreach ($commentIDs as $key => $commentID) {
        foreach ($commentID as $item) {
            $issue = Issue::where('id', $item)->first();

            if ($issue === null) {
                try {
                    $url = file_get_contents('https://documents.calibrate.be/issues/' . $item . '.json?key=' . $apiKey);
                    $json = json_decode($url, true);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                }

            

$issue = Issue::Create(['id'=>$item, 'name'=>$json['issue']['subject'], 'projectId'=>$json['issue']['project']['id'], 'priority'=>$json['issue']['priority']['id']]);

        }
    }
}
```

}

config/queue.php

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),

'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Is the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` used sync? Check in `config/queue.php`

Comment: 'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),

Comment: What about the value of the same in `.env` file?

Comment: BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

Comment: `QUEUE_CONNECTION` should be redis or database or whatever you want to use!

Comment: this doesn't make a difference :(

Comment: Did you run `php artisan config:clear` after changing the values? As they might have been cached?

Comment: aha, now i get "Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]"

Comment: Good. Now Install redis server and make sure it is running at port 6379, if you haven't.

Comment: In order to give an answer about:

> but I expected the page to load with the data I give it without the data from the api 

... please provide your action where you output the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Laravel uses the `sync` driver for handling queues.

Make sure that the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` config variable is set to either `database` or `redis` or any other service. 
The same can be set in the `.env` file as well as the `config/queue.php` file.

To use `database`, do

1. Run `php artisan queue:table` and `php artisan migrate`. This will create all the required tables to run.
2. Make sure you have the queue worker running in the background. You can do this in the console by running `php artisan queue:work`

To use `redis` , do

1. Install `sudo apt-get install redis-server` and start redis server `$ sudo systemctl enable redis-server.service`. (For Linux based systems)
2. Configure and set the redis specific variables in `.env` or `config/queue.php`

P.S. Run the `php artisan config:clear` command after making the changes so that the changes are reflected in the cache.

Comment: I am using a redis docker container so I think it is a bit different

Comment: For historical context: `QUEUE_DRIVER` was first used in Laravel configuration to define what queue you want to use,  `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is the successor.

Answer (score 2):

to use Redis as asynchronous in Laravel 5.8,  in .env file set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`